# How to disable animations for polymer's paper-dropdown-menu element?

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer, frontend, paper-elements

I need to disable all animations that happen when opening/closing polymer's `paper-dropdown-menu` element.
Documentation: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-dropdown-menu/elements/paper-dropdown-menu#property-noAnimations

The documentation shows that the element has a `noAnimations` property that I should be able to set to true to disable all animations, but it's not working for me.

```
        <paper-dropdown-menu
          noAnimations="true"
          selected="{{selected}}"
          attr-for-selected="name"
          vertical-offset="60"
        >
          <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="1">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sections}}">
                <paper-item name$="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

I expected that setting `noAnimations="true"` would disable all animations, but it does not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer attributes format is always lowercase and separated with dashes; so try:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu
  no-animations="true"
  selected="{{selected}}"
  attr-for-selected="name"
  vertical-offset="60"
>
...
```

instead:

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu
      noAnimations="true"
      selected="{{selected}}"
      attr-for-selected="name"
      vertical-offset="60"
    >
```